# What's wrong with my IIS/JNLP configuration?

Tags: iis, java

I'm attempting to serve up Java applications via JNLP.  It's MicroSoft Server 2008 IIS, with the ".jnlp application/x-java-jnlp-file" mime-type added.  The application launches fine from Solaris/FireFox clients.  However, when a JNLP launch is attempted from a Windows Vista client, the JNLP file opens in Wordpad!  JNLP launches on the same client, from other servers launch the application just fine.  Apparently one of us has missed a step somewhere in the server setup.  Anyone got an idea what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. Turns out to just be broken JRE plug-ins on the boxes I was using for testing. Nevermind.